# How to animate UITableView to slide up when showing the bottom cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, animation, uiviewanimation

I have a tableview and its bottom cell is special. Every time the table reloads, I want the bottom cell to slide up and the upper part of the table seems to be pushed up.

Like this:
[image]

How can I implement this animation? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to review [ask]. It's not really clear what you want to do, or what you have done so far that isn't giving you the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the `tableView` to scroll to a certain row with animation. If that cell is last, just call this after reload:

```
let scrollToIndexPath = IndexPath(row: numberOfRows - 1, section: 0)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: scrollToIndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

`.bottom` means you want to scroll to the bottom of the visible `tableView`.